# SmtpClient not connecting when the server is sign out (Error Code: 10060)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, smtpclient, gmail-imap

We have a program that sends an email for approval and extracting the reply using SSE.

In local computer the program is working, no error encountered. However when the program is published in our server we're experiencing some SockectException with the native error code 10060

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpBcR.png)

We're using SSE to check all the inbox using this code

```
public class MailRepository
{
    private readonly string mailServer, login, password;
    private readonly int port;
    private readonly bool ssl;

    public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
    {
        this.mailServer = mailServer;
        this.port = port;
        this.ssl = ssl;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMessage> GetAllMails()
    {
        var messages = new List<IMessage>();

        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect(mailServer, port, ssl);

            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            client.Authenticate(login, password);

            // The Inbox folder is always available on all IMAP servers...
            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
            var results = inbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, SearchQuery.All);
            foreach (var uniqueId in results.UniqueIds)
            {
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(uniqueId);
                var sender = message.From.FirstOrDefault();

                messages.Add(new IMessage() { 
                    htmlBody = message.HtmlBody,
                    body = message.TextBody,
                    subject = message.Subject,
                    sender = sender == null ? "": (sender as MailboxAddress).Address,
                    messageID = uniqueId
                });

                //Mark message as read
                //inbox.AddFlags(uniqueId, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 var mail = new MailRepository("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["approvalEmail"], "passwordhere")
```

And the program also sends email

```
public string SendContract()
        {
            //var img = Regex.Match(Request["orderscontent"], @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;

            email mail = new email();

            mail.server = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.server.Port = 587;
            mail.server.EnableSsl = true;
            mail.server.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["approvalEmail"], "passwordhere");
            //mail.server.Timeout = 10000;
            mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["approvalEmail"]);

            mail.To.Add(Request["email"]);
            mail.Subject = "DO Copy";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            mail.Attachments.Add(
                new Attachment(
                    new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Request["orderscontent"])),
                    string.Format("DO_copy_{0:MMddyyyyHHmm}.pdf", DateTime.Now)
                )
            );

            mail.Send();

            return "Sent!";
        }
```

Both of the program return [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpBcR.png). But we notice when we sign in the server the program is working. But when the server is signed out it returns an error, So im not sure if the problem is from the server or the code.

Comment: Have you tried socket connection in the same server with different application? If the application also not working, then it could be a server network issue. You may need to check group policy or server configuration.  So far it sounds doesn't like a code error.

Comment: I try a new application and the same behavior happens. i don't understand why it is working once we logged in the server. is there some services connected to smtp (or gmail if ever) that needed to be run even the server is logged out.

Comment: I think you could try to enable process monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to trace the network and service status. It would probably tell us what's going on when you are sign in and sign out